# Scala Spark - empty map on DataFrame column for map(String, Int)

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, dataframe

I am joining two DataFrames, where there are columns of a type `Map[String, Int]`

I want the merged DF to have an empty map `[]` and not `null` on the `Map` type columns.

```
val df = dfmerged.
  .select("id"),
          coalesce(col("map_1"), lit(null).cast(MapType(StringType, IntType))).alias("map_1"),
          coalesce(col("map_2"), lit(Map.empty[String, Int])).alias("map_2")
```

for a `map_1` column, a `null` will be inserted, but I'd like to have an **empty map**
map_2 is giving me an error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class
>   scala.collection.immutable.Map$EmptyMap$ Map()

I've also tried with an `udf` function like:

```
case class myStructMap(x:Map[String, Int])
val emptyMap = udf(() => myStructMap(Map.empty[String, Int]))
```

also did not work.

when I try something like:

`.select( coalesce(col("myMapCol"), lit(map())).alias("brand_viewed_count")...`

or

`.select(coalesce(col("myMapCol"), lit(map().cast(MapType(LongType, LongType)))).alias("brand_viewed_count")...`

I get the error:

> cannot resolve 'map()' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast
>   MapType(NullType,NullType,false) to MapType(LongType,IntType,true);

Answer (score 10):

In Spark 2.2

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit

val df = Seq((1L, null), (2L, Map("foo" -> "bar"))).toDF("id", "map")

df.withColumn("map", coalesce($"map", typedLit(Map[String, Int]()))).show
// +---+-----------------+
// | id|              map|
// +---+-----------------+
// |  1|            Map()|
// |  2|Map(foobar -> 42)|
// +---+-----------------+
```

Before

```
df.withColumn("map", coalesce($"map", map().cast("map<string,int>"))).show
// +---+-----------------+
// | id|              map|
// +---+-----------------+
// |  1|            Map()|
// |  2|Map(foobar -> 42)|
// +---+-----------------+
```