# How to create a typed empty MapType?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe schema that I want to match that has a column of type `MapType(StringType(), StringType())`. I tried the following implementations (using Spark 2.2.1):

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as fx
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([[1]], ['id'])
df = df.withColumn("map", fx.udf(dict, MapType(StringType(), StringType()))())
df = df.withColumn("map2", fx.create_map().cast(MapType(StringType(), StringType())))
```

The second attempt without the udf gives me this casting error:

```python
cannot resolve 'map()' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast MapType(NullType,NullType,false) to MapType(StringType,StringType,true)
```

Is there a correct way to write the second implementation (without the UDF)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala Spark - empty map on DataFrame column for map(String, Int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111778/scala-spark-empty-map-on-dataframe-column-for-mapstring-int)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the "correct way" but here is a way to do this without the `udf`:

Create a new dataframe by specifying a schema, and do a `crossJoin()`:

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1]], ['id'])

data = [({},)]
schema = StructType([StructField("map2", MapType(StringType(), StringType()))])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df.crossJoin(df2).show()
+---+-----+
| id| map2|
+---+-----+
|  1|Map()|
+---+-----+
```